# Can a "normal" user see all processes with htop?

Tags: terminal, performance, administrator

Can I see all processes with `htop` or does it make sense to use `sudo htop`?

I use htop in the terminal (installed via brew / homebrew). My useraccount on the macbook is a default user no special rights restrictions. OS-Version Mojave.

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/htop

Comment: You can see all of them as a user, but you won‘t be able to act on those you don‘t have rights (e.g. kill them).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can see all processes with htop as the default user.

Note that if you for example use virtualization to run multiple systems on one, htop will only show you the virtualization program as a process - not the processes running within that virtual machine.

Whether or not it makes sense to use `sudo htop` depends on the context. If you run `htop` as an ordinary user, you do not get the full information on all processes - i.e. processes started by other user's will be listed, but with incomplete numbers. If you need the full set of data about processes started by other users, `sudo htop` definitely makes sense.

On the other hand, as soon as you start `htop` with `sudo` you need to aware that you have full privileges - for example it is possible to kill system processes and programs started by other users. If this not your intention, starting `htop` without `sudo` removes the risk of doing that by mistake.